# Selectize - jQuery search/select element parsing json from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, selectize.js

I am using the GitHub example of selectize that I have modified to retrieve json from my own server.

http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/

For this example I have skipped the db call and am just forcing back some set data. The select box does not get populated with the json that is returned by the php script and I can't figure out why.

json response:

```
$result['users'] = array(
    array(
        'id'=>1,
        'first_name'=>"Sherd",
        'last_name'=>"Jerrod",
        'email'=>"sherd@jerrod.com"
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>2,
        'first_name'=>"Ned",
        'last_name'=>"Wolf",
        'email'=>"Ned@Wolf.com"
    ),  
);

$json = json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;
```

Select box:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Selectize.js Demo</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <!--[if IE 8]><script src="js/es5.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1>Selectize.js</h1>
            <div class="demo">
                <h2>Loading + Custom Scoring</h2>
                <p>This demo shows how to integrate third-party data and override the scoring method.</p>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="select-repo">Repository:</label>
                    <select id="select-repo" class="repositories" placeholder="Pick a repository..."></select>
                </div>
                <script>
                $('#select-repo').selectize({
                    valueField: 'url',
                    labelField: 'name',
                    searchField: 'name',
                    options: [],
                    create: false,
                    render: {
                        option: function(item, escape) {
                            return '<div>'+ item.first_name +'</div>';
                        }
                    },
                    score: function(search) {
                        var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
                        return function(item) {
                            return score(item) * (1 + Math.min(item.watchers / 100, 1));
                        };
                    },
                    load: function(query, callback) {
                        if (!query.length) return callback();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost/random/return.php?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query),

                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            error: function() {
                                callback();
                            },
                            success: function(res) {
                                callback(res.users);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the API's I guess `selectize` uses `array` as source. But what you are recieving is a `JSON` response. Try converting it into a `array` and try

You could map the array onto an array of objects, like this:

```
var results= $.parseJSON(your_JSON_response);
var items = results.map(function(x) { return { item: x }; });
```

Then you can use "labelField" and "valueField" to specify the value:

```
    labelField: "item",
    valueField: "item"
```

Comment: No you cannot returnan array coz, thats a php array, you cant use php array in javascript and hence json :)

Comment: That's what I thought. Also the example of selectize that used the github api returns json and that all works fine, I don't understand why need to map the json into a js array?